# React native bottom Sheet the modal only opens when the flatlist has loaded

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog, expo, bottom-sheet, flatlist

I use this lib:

https://gorhom.github.io/react-native-bottom-sheet/components/bottomsheetflatlist

I show a Modal, and in the modal is a flatlist.

The problem is, if I press modal open, I wait for 1 second and then the modal is opened because the modal shows only when the flatlist has loaded. Can I open the modal even if the flatlist has not loaded?

```js
// ref
const bottomSheetModalRef = React.useRef(null);

// variables
const snapPoints = React.useMemo(() => ['25%', '50%'], []);

// callbacks
const handlePresentModalPress = React.useCallback(() => {
    bottomSheetModalRef.current?.present();
}, []);
const handleSheetChanges = React.useCallback((index) => {
    console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
}, []);

const renderBackdrop = React.useCallback(
  props => <BottomSheetBackdrop {...props} pressBehavior="close" />,
  [],
);

const renderItemData = ({ item }) => (
  <View style={styles.item}>
      <Text style={styles.plus}>+{item.plus}</Text>
      <Text style={styles.cost}>{I18n.t('cost')}: {item.cost}</Text>
      <View style={styles.uppitem_container}>
          <Text>{item.text}</Text>
      </View>
  </View>
);

<BottomSheetModal
  ref={bottomSheetModalRef}
  index={1}
  backgroundStyle={{backfaceVisibility: 'visible', backgroundColor: 'green',}}
  backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
  snapPoints={snapPoints}
  onChange={handleSheetChanges}
>
    <BottomSheetFlatList
      data={itemInfo[0]?.item?.upp}
      keyExtractor={item => item.plus.toString()}
      renderItem={renderItemData}
      initialNumToRender={1}
      updateCellsBatchingPeriod={100}
      maxToRenderPerBatch={2}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
    />
</BottomSheetModal>
```